# GCP Cloud Storage - Wildcard Prefix List

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

This is a question of how to acomplish a certain task with the GCP Cloud Storage API.

I have a bucket with a "folder" structure as follows:

`ID / Year / Month / Day / FILES`

I need to search for all files with the following format: `ID/2016/04/03/`. I had hoped I could use a * in the prefix (`*/2016/04/03/`), but this does not work.

Anyone know a way to make this happen without iterating every top level folder myself?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API support for wildcard expressions - just for prefix queries.

When you say "iterating every top level folder myself" it sounds like you mean manually listing them in your client code? You can avoid doing that by doing a query that specifies `delimiter="/"` and `prefix=""` to find the top-level "folders". You would then iterate over that list and construct prefix queries to list the individual objects within the given date-named folder.

If it's possible for you to restructure your names, you could avoid having to do the extra prefix+delimiter query and iteration , so the top level is the date, e.g.,

> Year / Month / Day / ID / FILES

Comment: Unfortunately this makes the most sense for us internally. Perhaps we could make it a feature request?  ;)