# Google cloud storage: move specific zip files from one bucket to another

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Team,

I'm trying to parameterize the file name while unzipping the file . But i'm getting below error. It is working when i mention full file name in 'sourceFileObject' and remove match_glob

> TypeError: list_blobs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'match_glob'

I'm using : google-cloud-storage==2.5.0 in requirements.txt

please find my sample code below:

````
def fileUnzip(data,content):

    """
    Decompression logic to unzip a file based on the compression format
    """
    storage_client = storage.Client('projectname')
    source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bucket-1")
    output_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bucket-2")
    sourceFileObject = "tm*.zip"
    if ("*" in sourceFileObject ):
        prefix  = sourceFileObject.split("*")[0]
        delimiter = sourceFileObject.split("*")[-1]
        print('prefix is: ', prefix)
        print('match_glob is: ', sourceFileObject)
    blobs = source_bucket.list_blobs(match_glob=sourceFileObject)
    [blob.name for blob in blobs if '*.zip' in blob.name ]
    compressedData = io.BytesIO(blobs.download_as_string()) ```
````

Comment: Ignoring the error for a moment, you should know that list_blobs can't take wildcards like gsutil.  Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384854/gcp-cloud-storage-wildcard-prefix-list

Comment: Actually, I followed the link to get here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800231/google-cloud-storage-list-blob-objects-with-specific-file-name/77417798#77417798

Answer (score 0):

`match_glob` is only available since the 2.10 version. Upgrade your dependency to fix the issue
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/2.10.0/google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket#google_cloud_storage_bucket_Bucket_list_blobs

Comment: Actually, when I change it to 2.10 it is giving a different error:
"AttributeError: 'HTTPIterator' object has no attribute 'download_as_string"

Comment: Yes, blobs is an iterator, and you can only invoke the function on a blob (a single element in the blob array).